# Please tell me with references for this phrase

Tags: idioms

I would like to know the meaning of phrase from the lyrics of PaPa song "keep those shoes upon my feet".

> Every day my papa would work
> To help to make ends meet
> To see that we would eat
> Keep those shoes upon my feet

Does it mean the cost of everything for his son? Can be able to use keep.....upon? What does it mean?

Comment: What is your difficulty here? Is it the use of "upon"? Do you know what "make ends meet" means? Do you understand the use of "would". The last line is the easiest. "Papa used to work so that the family would have money, food and clothing"  No hidden meaning.

Answer (score 1):

It means that papa can afford to buy shoes for you - not go around with bare feet.

There is a companion phrase

> put food on the table

which means the same thing: the breadwinner is earning enough to look after the family properly. The two phrases are sometimes used together, such as in the hymn [Thank you Lord](https://namethathymn.com/hymn-lyrics/viewtopic.php?t=11186)

> There's a roof up above me, I have a good place to sleep
> There's food on my table and shoes on my feet
> You gave me Your love, Lord, and a fine family
> Thank You, Lord, for Your blessings on me